# if statement not working as expected with background colors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, if-statement

So what I am trying to do is make it so that when the background-color of my div is black and I click on a button it will change to black. And when it's orange it will change to orange.
(I am just playing around with it to learn something about jquery, so please explain what and why you did something and keep it as simple as possible thanks!)

function for changing the background-color of the button (so far)

```
var color = $('#square').css('backgroundColor');
$('#vak1').click(function() {
    if (color == 'rgb(0, 0, 255)' || color == 'black')
        $('#vak1').css('backgroundColor', 'Black') || $('#vak1').css('border', '1px solid Black') ||  $('#vak1').prop('disable', true); 
    else
        $('#vak1').css('backgroundColor', 'Orange');

    $('#vak1').css('border', '1px solid Orange');
    $('#vak1').prop('disable', true);                          
});
```

function for giving the 1en2 button its color

```
$('#blablu').click(function() {
    var clicks = $(this).data('clicks');
    if (clicks) {
        $('#hoi').css('backgroundColor', 'Black');
    } else {
        $('#hoi').css('backgroundColor', 'Orange');
    }
    $(this).data("clicks", !clicks);
});
```

Buttons and the divs

```
<button class="vak1" id="vak1"></button>
<button id="blablu">
    1 en 2
</button>
<div id="square"></div>
```

Comment: $(this).data('clicks')... there is no data element 'clicks'

Comment: Why not use a CSS class for orange, and a CSS class for black, use .hasClass to detect if it has one or the other, and then switch them using .addClass/.removeClass